# does FP make code run faster in V8?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, jit

Recently i have played a lot with Javascript(Chrome) there are some things that came to my mind.

1. V8 has a JIT which make code running faster.
2. Functional programming means you write logic into functions and invoke/combine them by chain, means core functions will be invoked frequently(not its real definition just for get my point).
3. JIT is one best practice of `exchange time with space` basically in first time cache machine code of high-level functions and run caches in next time.

So may i say that apps will be faster if write code in FP way and run by VM that has JIT feature.

Comment: I don't follow - why is it that you believe the code will execute faster under V8's JIT if written in a functional style? (as opposed to a traditional imperative JS style...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good read on this subject is here: http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/

Particularly the section that talks about how V8 compiles and injects JIT code

> How V8 compiles JavaScript code?
>
> V8 has two compilers!
>
> A “Full” Compiler that can generate good code for any JavaScript: good
>   but not great JIT code. The goal of this compiler is to generates code
>   quickly. To achieve its goal, it doesn’t do any type analysis and
>   doesn”t know anything about types. Instead, it uses an Inline Caches
>   or “IC” strategy to refine knowledge about types while the program
>   run. IC is very efficient and bring about 20 times speed improvement.
>
> An Optimizing Compiler that produces great code for most of the
>   JavaScript language. It comes later and re-compiles hot functions. The
>   optimizing compiler takes types from the Inline Cache and make
>   decisions about how to optimize the code better. However, some
>   language features are not supported yet like try/catch block for
>   instance. (The workaround for try/catch blocks is to write the “non
>   stable” code into a function and to call the function in the try
>   block)

In short, your fastest code is that which does not modify objects or prototypical function definitions after they've been defined

Comment: thank you for comment very good point at what is the fastest code in V8.